# How is Swift's "implicitly unwrapped optionals" different from Java's "autoboxing" of integers?

Tags: java, swift, option-type, autoboxing

Is the idea of Swift's "*implicitly unwrapped optionals*" the same as Java's "*autoboxing*" of integers? The following runtime exception would only be possible in Swift if `xObj` is declared an "implicitly unwrapped option":

```
Integer xObj = new Integer(-1);  
xObj = null;  // could do this with an implicitly unwrapped optional as well.
Integer.valueOf(xObj); // <-- exception. Integer.valueOf(int x); couldn't deal with this.
```

The point being that "implicitly unwrapped optionals" CAN be nil, but you better be careful and not use them when a non-nil reference is expected, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the idea of Swift's "implicitly unwrapped optionals" the same as Java's "autoboxing" of integers?

*Same*? No. That's too strong of a statement. *Serve a similar purpose, in some cases?* Yes.

Autoboxing is used in Java for 2 main reasons:

1. To convert value types (the primitives) to objects, so that they can be stored in collections, like `ArrayList` and `HashMap`.

   - The only primitives that need this treatment are `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `boolean`, and `char`. Hence why those are the only types with auto-box object equivalents. Java autoboxing is limited to only these types, whereas in Swift, Optionals are applicable to all types.
   - Swift's native collections can store value types, so this conversion isn't necessary.
   - Foundation's collections can only store pointers. When using them, Swift does a similar thing as Java, by automatically boxing numerical types into `NSNumber` objects.
   - Swift's Optional is an enum, a value type, regardless of whether it's wrapping a reference type or a value type.
2. Allow for nullability without using a sentinel value. I.e. returning `null` instead of `-1`, `Integer.MIN`, etc.

   - This is the what Swift's Optionals are for.

Comment: I understand autoboxing in Java and why you use it. Rather, I am new to Swift. I what to understand "implicitly unwrapped optionals" in terms of Java's autoboxing.

Comment: My biggest trouble is with Swift's enum being *value types* as opposed to objects. Thanks for your help, and I've got more reading to do!

Comment: I had to state the obvious (with regards to java) for the sake of contrasting it with Swift. What about enums as value types gives you trouble?

Comment: Java enum are classes. Upon the first reference to them one instance is created in the heap. `SomeEnum.class.getCanonicalName()`. Presumably, if Java had to re-arrange memory and change the memory address of the enum object, nothing breaks.